# how to submit a form and add record to the sqlite 3 database using django and jqyery with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, sqlite

i have a form that request user input in order to save the records into the sqlite 3 database.

the problem is that before i tried to add the upload image field to the form the data was saved correctly.
but now  the system first request that i add blank and null to **num filed** , **date field** , **issent filed**.

then it display the below error :

> > File "C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop\Final new\djangoWeb\views.py", line 160, in post_new
> >         id=form.te2chira_id AttributeError: 'SaveTe2chira' object has no attribute 'te2chira_id'

- added  picture field to the model
- added picture element in the form
- added the input tag  in the html
- send the data through AJAX  to the view
- getting the data from ajax request and added to the view function

## models.py

```
class te2chira(models.Model):
    te2chira_id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True)
    num = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    te2chira_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='DEFAULT VALUE', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='DEFAULT VALUE', blank=True, null=True)
    is_sent=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pictures/%d/%m/%Y/',null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.te2chira_id)
```

## form.py

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import te2chira, destination

class SaveTe2chira(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = te2chira
        fields = ['num','title', 'description','picture' ]
```

## html

```
<form method="POST" class="form-style-9" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
<li>
 <input type="file" id="img" name="img"/>   
</li>
<li>
<input type="submit" class="field-style field-full align-none" id="save" value="save" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function(){
                $('#save').on('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault()
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('num',$('#num').val())
                    formData.append('title',$('#title').val())
                    formData.append('text',$('#text').val())
                    formData.append('issent', 0)
                    formData.append('img', document.getElementById('img').files[0])



                $.ajax({
                    url:'/create/te2chira',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:formData,
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    headers:{
                        'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
                    }
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    document.location = "/creativePageSend.html"
                    alert('data saved')


                }).fail(function(err){
                    alert('no data was saved')
                })
            })
        })
</script>

</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**before i add the image field the javascript was:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                 $(function(){
                    $('#save').on('click',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault()

                        num=$('#num').val()
                        title=$('#title').val()
                        text=$('#text').val()
                        issent=0
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/create/te2chira',
                        method:'POST',
                        data: {
                            // y:year,
                            // d:date,
                            n:num,
                            ti:title,
                            te:text,
                            s:0
                        },
                        headers:{
                            'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
                        }
                    }).done(function(msg) {
                        document.location = "/creativePageSend.html"
                        alert('data saved')


                    }).fail(function(err){
                        alert('no data was saved')
                    })
                })
            })
        </script>
```

## views.py

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = SaveTe2chira(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("valid form")
            form.save()
            id=form.te2chira_id
            print(id)
            request.session['idTe2chira']=id
            return render(request,'./creativePageSend.html',{'id':id})
        else:
            print("invalid form")
```

**before i add the image field  in the form the function was :**

```
def post_new(request):
    title = request.POST['ti']
    description = request.POST['te']
    num=request.POST['n']
    issent=request.POST['s']
    n=te2chira.objects.create(title=title,te2chira_date=timezone.datetime.now(),description=description,num=num,is_sent=issent)
    print(timezone.datetime.now())
    n.save()
    id=n.te2chira_id
    request.session['idTe2chira']=id
    return render(request,'./creativePageSend.html',{'id':id})
```

submit the form with all the fields  and saved the record in the database

Answer (score 0):

SaveTe2chira is the form, as the error says the form doesn't have an attribute "te2chira_id".

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want to save the ID of the newly created object in the session. So you need to use that object, which is returned from the form save call:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        id = obj.te2chira_id
        request.session['idTe2chira'] = id
```

Note, your Ajax `done()` function seems strange; you can't redirect to a template, and anyway your view is already returning the rendered value of that template. Your done function should update the page DOM to show the contents of that response.

Comment: i tried your answer  now it doesn't save the user input value instead it save default value or null

Comment: That has **nothing whatsoever** to do with my answer. But presumably it is because for some reason you are sending the data as `n`, `ti`, `te` and `s` instead of  the actual field names.